# Matplotlib: two x axis and two y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've seen several question asking how to add a secondary x or y axis but none asking if adding both at the same time is possible.

I know `ax.twinx()` and `ax.twiny()` are used to add either another `y` or `x` axis respectively, but how would one go about adding both?

Here's an example of two curves with different x,y ranges:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate two sets of random data.
x1 = np.random.randn(50)
y1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
x2 = np.random.randn(20)+15.
y2 = np.linspace(10, 20, 20)

# Plot both curves.
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
plt.plot(x1, y1, c='r')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.plot(x2, y2, c='b')

plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

and what I'm after is something like this:

[image]

where the right `y` axis and the top `x` axis correspond to the blue curve.

Can this be done?

Comment: Good question, I was looking into this myself. :)

Comment: just use both, the third `axes` will be what you want.

Comment: @tcaswell -- This was what I was about to suggest trying.  It's good to see that you've already answered this before :)

Comment: @tcaswell indeed this is a duplicate of that question, I missed that. I'll vote to close. Thanks you!

Comment: @Gabriel That is why SO has the duplicate linking scheme, not everyone describes the same problem with the same words.  The more sign posts the better.

Comment: @tcaswell if you have the time please stop by a new question that came about after applying your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230926/no-label-for-secondary-y-axis-in-plot. Thanks!